# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'username' of 'match.parse' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, use-effect

I have a problem with some error.
I've been trying to fix this for a week but I still can't find what is a problem....

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'username' of 'match.parse' as it is undefined.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import qs from 'qs';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import PostList from '../../components/posts/PostList';
import { listPosts } from '../../modules/posts';

const PostListContainer = ({ location, match }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { posts, error, loading, user } = useSelector(
        ({ posts, loading, user }) => ({
            posts: posts.posts, 
            error: posts.error,
            loading: loading['posts/LIST_POSTS'],
            user: user.user,
        }),
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        const { username } = match.parse;
        const { tag, page } = qs.parse(location.search, {
            ignoreQueryPrefix: true,
        });
        dispatch(listPosts({ tag, username, page }));
    }, [dispatch, location.search]);

    return (
        <PostList 
            loading={loading}
            error={error}
            posts={posts}
            showWriteButton={user}
        />
    );
};


export default withRouter(PostListContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, because `match.parse` is `undefined`, you cannot destruct `username` from it, meaning you cannot do:

```
const { username } = match.parse;
```

The left side's curly braces are called a [destructor](http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingShorthandNotation) in ECMAScript because it "destructs" the value from the right-hand side object. It's the same as:

```
const username = match.parse.username;
```

and if `match.parse` is `undefined`, it's the same as:

```
const username = undefined.username;
```

which obviously is wrong.

So, try `console.log`ging `match.parse` and see if it is actually `undefined`. If so, you need to debug why it is.